# Install Bioconductor Packages in R 4.0.0

Tags: r, bioconductor

I need a package from Bioconductor-Library. So I installed BiocManager-Package. However I can not install Packages via

```
BiocManager::repositories()
```

There is just the message:

```
in file(con r ) internetopenurl failed 'a connection with the server could not be established'
```

However as told, I am able to install packages from CRAN as BiocManager. Is there another way to install Bioconductor-Packages? Maybe put this repository into preferences, but with which URL?

Answer (score 2):

Go to BioConductor webpage for any package and follow the instruction.  E.g. for [BioBase](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/Biobase.html):

```
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
    install.packages("BiocManager") 
BiocManager::install("Biobase")
```

Answer (score 0):

I found myself needing to install packages from bioconductor, it was as simple as:

```r
install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install(c("GenomicFeatures", "AnnotationDbi"))
```

That will install bioconductor packages 'GenomicFeatures', and 'AnnotationDbi' (you can replace those with other [bioconductor packages](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/))

#### Reference

- https://www.bioconductor.org/install/